# Open a Wordpress portfolio thumbnail as lightbox instead if linking to portfolio item page

Tags: wordpress

Currently the theme I am using links each portfolio thumbnail to its corresponding portfolio item page. I would like to link the thumbnail to the larger image using lightbox.

The current shortcode is:

```
$output .= '<li>';
                    $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">';
                        $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'portfolio-item', array('class'=>'scale-with-grid' ) );
                        $output .= '<div>';
                            $output .= '<span class="ico"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>';
                            $output .= '<h6>'. the_title(false, false, false) .'</h6>';
                        $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '</a>';
                $output .= '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery Colorbox Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-colorbox/) for achieving the functionality that you want

Comment: I'm afraid that this does not work. It adds the colorbox link to standard images within posts and pages, but not to the portfolio images.

Comment: Check this link and let me know. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6yqzyK1vIoRV0o3RG43SGRTZGM/edit

Comment: Yes, both of these checkboxes have been ticked